# Next.js site hosted on VPS Nginx Server doesn't show a favicon

Tags: nginx, next.js, vps, favicon, next.js14

I recently encountered a problem with my Next.js website. I host it on VPS server, using Nginx. Even though a page has a link for a favicon `<link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico'` and also Nginx serves a favicon:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
                alias /root/public_html/favicon.ico;
          }
```

When you type in a browser lotusite.pl/favicon.ico, an icon appears on a center, but it's not displaying on a tab. Lastly I had a problem with this, when you had entered this url there was a 403 error, but changing permissions helped. Unfortunatelly it didn't help width displaying it on a tab. I cleared a browser cache, tried visiting page in different browsers, also on different devices, but still nothing. Here's my project structure:

```
lotusite/ 
 --- public/ 
        --- favicon.ico
 --- src/ 
        --- app/ 
            --- layout.js
```

Layout.js:

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
      icon: [
        {
          url: "/images/favicon.ico", 
          href: "/images/favicon.ico", 
        },
      ],
    },
};
```

The icon is showing when I use a development server on my local PC, but it doesn't on VPS server.

I tried using  but it was only giving me errors. Asked ChatGPT, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Asked Gemini exactly the same question and it gave me the answer that worked:
Troubleshooting Steps:

Verify File Path: Make sure both layout.js and Nginx configuration point to the same location (/favicon.ico).
Hard Refresh: Perform a hard refresh in the browser to clear the cache.
Nginx Content-Type: Add the add_header directive in Nginx as mentioned above.
It actually somehow worked. I'm leaving this question in case someone has exact same problem as me, because I haven't seen anything explaining what to do in this situation.

Comment: Your `layout.js` file is referring to an `images` directory that does not exist in your projet structure. This has to be fixed.